# iPhone doesn't copy time-lapse videos to Windows 8.1 PC

Tags: windows, iphone, ios

My iPhone XR is running IOS 12. It shows up in Windows 8.1 and i can copy/move photos and normal videos to my PC without any problem.

Any video that's not *normal* such as time lapse won't copy. Windows shows the copy begin to work, then I get an error "Device not responding". The copy aborts and I can't copy anything (pics or normal videos) without POPO the iPhone.

Anyone know how to fix this? It seems odd the the iPhone mounts and lets me copy photos and most videos but somehow the iPhone seems to "grab" any of the unusual videos and won't let the PC copy them. What's going on?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer - you need to set your iPhone to the following:

```
Settings > Photos > Where it says "Transfer to Mac or PC" Select "Keep Originals"
```

Thanks to Alecqz at Apple for the solution.